# Count Blanks, Spaces, and Hardcoded Nulls

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, null

I want to get counts of  Blanks, Spaces, and Hardcoded Nulls in fields using `arcpy.SearchCursor`. Is it possible? When I try to filter am getting `None` values only.

I tried the below code.

```
 cursorfields = arcpy.ListFields(featureclass_path)
    for field in cursorfields:
        cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureclass_path)
        for row in cursor:
            if (str(row.getValue(field.name)) == "Null"):
                
            if(str(row.getValue(field.name)) == "NULL"):
                
            if(str(row.getValue(field.name)) == "<Null>"):
               
            if(len(str(row.getValue(field.name))) == 0):
               
            if(not(str(row.getValue(field.name)) and str(row.getValue(field.name)).strip())):
```

Comment: Which ArcMap version do you have? You mean rows with only blanks/spaces and Null as a string, not actual `None`), so for example `saasd asdas` should not be counted since the blankspace is in the middle of a string?

Comment: @bera version 10.8

Comment: some fields have hardcoded nulls like <Null>, NULL, Null I want to check these three conditions. And if the field is " " I need to read it as empty. If the fields contain white spaces like "   "  should count the spaces.

Comment: The source of your data will dictate what you search for, for example shapefiles have no concept of a null value. They use a space to store nothing whilst a geodatabase can store a null. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use da.SearchCursor its faster.

Try using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) like this:

```
from collections import Counter
fc = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\jl_sample'
count = {' ', 'Null', 'NULL', '<Null>'}
textfields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc, field_type='String')]

cnt = Counter()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, textfields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for w in count.intersection(set(row)): #Set intersection (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp)
            cnt[w]+=1

cnt
Counter({u'Null': 1, u' ': 1})
```

My `<Null>` are actual `None`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Let me try.

Comment: Nice use of counter!

Comment: @bera which version of ArcMap you are using

Comment: 10.7.1. Doesnt the code work?

Comment: It's working. Thank you